# Find all recipes with just vegan products

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been trying to **find all recipes with just vegan products** but so far I just have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM recipes r INNER JOIN recipe_product rp ON r.id = rp.recipe_id
INNER JOIN products p ON rp.product_id = p.id 
INNER JOIN product_specificdiet ps ON p.id = ps.product_id 
INNER JOIN specificdiets sd ON ps.specific_diet_id = sd.id 
WHERE sd.type = 'VEGAN';
```

But that query is giving me all the products that are vegan for all the recipes.

No idea how could I resolve it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post a schema of your tables. Each answer related to the given info will be just a guess.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff postgresql

Comment: @SebastianS. I think more info is not required, you can see the joins there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two rules:

1. A product is vegan, if one of its specific diets is 'VEGAN'.
2. A recipe is vegan, if it only consists of vegan products.

In other words: A vegan recipe is a recipe for which `NOT EXISTS` any product that is `NOT IN` the set of vegan products.

```
select *
from recipes r
where not exists
(
  select null -- non-vegan ingredient
  from recipe_product rp 
  where rp.recipe_id = r.id
  and rp.product_id not in 
  (
    select ps.product_id -- vegan product
    from product_specificdiet ps
    join specificdiets sd ON ps.specific_diet_id = sd.id 
    where sd.type = 'VEGAN'
  )
);
```

Comment: Amazing, you prove that I do have recipes just with vegan products and works fine!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    re.*
FROM
    recipes re
WHERE
    re.id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            r.id
        FROM
            recipes r
        LEFT JOIN
            recipe_product rp ON r.id = rp.recipe_id
        LEFT JOIN
            products p ON rp.product_id = p.id 
        LEFT JOIN
            product_specificdiet ps ON p.id = ps.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN
            specificdiets sd ON ps.specific_diet_id = sd.id 
        WHERE 
            ISNULL(sd.type, '') != 'VEGAN';
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately,it is returning all the recipes that all the products have sd.type as NULL

Comment: @RicardoRomeroBenítez please see my edit and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM recipes r JOIN
     recipe_product rp
     ON r.id = rp.recipe_id JOIN
     products p
     ON rp.product_id = p.id JOIN
     product_specificdiet ps
     ON p.id = ps.product_id JOIN
     specificdiets sd
     ON ps.specific_diet_id = sd.id 
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (sd.type = 'VEGAN') = COUNT(*);
```

An alternative method would filter out ingredients that are not vegan and check for zero of them:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (sd.type <> 'VEGAN') = 0;
```

Postgres is one of the databases that allows you to specify `SELECT r.*` even though you are only aggregating by `r.id` -- because that is allowed when the aggregation key is a primary key.  In other databases, you may need to list the columns both in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` if you want additional columns.

Comment: Return nothing :/

Comment: @RicardoRomeroBenítez . . . I wonder if there are no recipes that are all vegan in your database -- perhaps because of things like "salt" that might not be listed as such.

Comment: You are absolutely right! That is what is happening

Comment: The answer for @Thorsten Kettner proves that I do have

Comment: I think the problem with this query is rather that it doesn't take into account that one product can cover multiple diets. I'd expect any 'VEGAN'  product to also be 'VEGETARIAN' for instance. So, the counting approach would require to count distinct products instead of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by joining to a sub-query. 
One that uses a filters the specific diets that only uses vegan types.

Untested notepad scribble :

```
SELECT r.*
FROM recipes r 
JOIN
(
  SELECT rp.recipe_id
  FROM recipe_product rp
  INNER JOIN products p 
    ON p.id = rp.product_id
  INNER JOIN product_specificdiet ps 
    ON ps.product_id = p.id
  LEFT JOIN specificdiets sd 
    ON sd.id = ps.specific_diet_id
  GROUP BY rp.recipe_id
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN sd.type = 'VEGAN' THEN sd.id END) = COUNT(*)
) q
ON q.recipe_id = r.id;
```